# SQL grouping rows by date and showing counts for each date

Tags: sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012, I have a list of transactions each with a timestamp for the time the transaction occurred. I would like to display a column of dates where transactions occurred and a second column showing the number of transactions that occurred for each date.

I've managed to display the column of dates where transactions occurred, but am having trouble with the second portion. My code for the first is:

```
select distinct convert(varchar(10), Timestamp, 111) as 'TransactionDates'
from Transactions
```

which returns dates where a transaction took place.

I assume that for the second part of the select statement where I'm finding the number of transactions for each day I use a count of the exact same statement like so:

```
select distinct convert( varchar(10), Timestamp, 111) as 'TransactionDates',
count(distinct convert( varchar(10), Timestamp, 111)) as 'NumTransactions'
from Transactions
```

which should result in a second column called `NumTransactions` with a count of how many times each date has been recorded in a row. I may be misinterpreting the proper use of the Count function or perhaps there is a much easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
SELECT d = CONVERT(DATE, [Timestamp]), c = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Transactions
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, [Timestamp])
ORDER BY d;
```

Please don't do this awful converting to a string trick to remove time. Why?

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time

Also try to avoid using reserved words like `timestamp` for column names. `timestamp` of what, for starters?

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. This is the first time I've used the convert function and I didnt even think about just using Date. One of those palm-to-face moments.

Comment: I've been given a database to mine for various things, but am not allowed to alter the database itself. My naming conventions would be much more descriptive.